# Gson is not working with Java based app using AWS Lambda

Tags: java, json, gson, appium

I am developing an app to trigger the AWS Lambda in Java.

**Note:** My app uses Maven as the build tool.

To trigger the Lambda, I need to send the JSON object in the request. I'm trying to use Gson Library. But it's not working.

I'm getting issue with import statement when adding this line of code.

```
String inputForLambda = new Gson().toJson(trip.getCreateTripRequest().toString());
```

I have added the following maven dependencies in the **pom.xml**:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.16.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Kindly help me in solving the issue. I have tried in all possible ways. Yet I'm unable to figure out where is the issue.

Comment: what is the issue? Please put the stacktrace

Comment: I get an error at the import statement.
import com.google.gson.Gson;
I am unable to use Gson in the below line.
String inputForLambda = new Gson().toJson(trip.getCreateTripRequest().toString());

Comment: Either use Gson or Jackson. Decide which one you want to use for your project.

Comment: Just use only `com.google.code.gson:Gson:2.10.1`.That's more than enough. No need to add other dependencies.

Comment: I have used the below maven dependency.
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
   <artifactId>Gson</artifactId>
   <version>2.10.1</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Can you run the command `mvn clean install` ?

Comment: Yes, i have run the command. Yet i receive the same error.

Comment: Are you using a `module-info.java` file? In that case you have to add `requires com.google.gson` to it.